# Is iterating over a javascript map.values() iterator using null termination a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, iterator

I'm fairly new to Javascript and currently working through a bunch of linting errors. Looking for clarity on this one specifically.

I have a map in the format [int, object], the map is obtained by JSON.parse-ing some data from server and putting into a key value map.

I need to iterate over the set of objects. As I understand it, this: 
`for(item in/of map) {}`
is not performant and using an iterator is preferable.

When I get an iterator for my map's values using `const iterator = map.values();` and test using

```
while(!iterator.done) {
  iterator.next();
}
```

I find that this loops infinately, first through the map and then through 'undefined'.

My current solution is the following:

```
let item;
const iterator = map.values();
while ((item = iterator.next().value) != null) {
 // do stuff with item
}
```

This feels like a reasonable solution but I'm hoping for some clarity as to whether the assignment inside the while loop, or relying on null termination is a bad idea in javascript; or if there is a more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think most devs do:

```
let value;
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => { value = obj[key]; console.log(value)});
```

Dealing with the interals of iterators is a bit clunky for such a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should check value returned by `next` for `done` property.

```js
let result = it.next();
while(!result.done) {
  result = iterator.next();
}
```